# To convert a dict (with list of keys and values) into list of dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

I have a dict with a list of keys, and the values are stored separate in a list of lists:

```
obj = {
    'keys': ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], 
    'items': [['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], ['value4', 'value5', 'value6'], ['value7', 'value8', 'value9']]
}
```

The desired output is to 'merge' them into a list of dict like this:

```
[
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'},
    {'key1': 'value4', 'key2': 'value5', 'key3': 'value6'},
    {'key1': 'value7', 'key2': 'value8', 'key3': 'value9'}
]
```

I have tried this direct approach

```
result = []
for item in obj['items']:
        result.append(dict(zip(obj['keys'], item)))
```

and also shortened it to this

```
[dict(zip(obj['keys'], item)) for item in obj['items']]
```

Are there other alternatives to achieve the desired output?

And may I know what is the name of this 'merge' manipulation?

Comment: Your solution is perfectly good. I see no reason to introduce other modules (such as *pandas*) to do this. I have no idea what this technique is known as ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

obj = {
    'keys': ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], 
    'items': [['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], ['value4', 'value5', 'value6'], ['value7', 'value8', 'value9']]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(obj['items'], columns=obj['keys'])
df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

result:

```
[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'},
 {'key1': 'value4', 'key2': 'value5', 'key3': 'value6'},
 {'key1': 'value7', 'key2': 'value8', 'key3': 'value9'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[ dict(zip(obj['keys'], item)) for item in obj['items'] ]
```

Your final line has a combination of these components:

- list comprehension, ie, `[ function(x) for x in list_x ]`
- zipping of 2 lists, ie, `zip(list1, list2)`

Perhaps these are the names of the 'merge' manipulation you are looking for?